# Can't open PDF with SVWebViewController (iOS)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf, ios7

I'm using **SVWebViewController** on my app for 6 months.
Since *iOS7*, I can't open PDF. No error occurred but I don't have any content display.

However, if I request an basic URL like google, the content appear.

The problem is only when I try to open PDF files.

I use this library : [SVWebViewController](https://github.com/samvermette/SVWebViewController)

I call the viewController with this code :

```
 SVModalWebViewController *modalVC = [[SVModalWebViewController alloc]
 initWithAddress:xmlParserContenuAppelOffre.file];

 [self presentViewController:modalVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Someone had the same problem and can resolve it ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem it's really occurred by **SVWebViewController**.

SVWebViewController use `UIWebview loadRequest:`, it doesn't work with PDF Url but works with google url.
So I guess is a *problem with iOS7*, because I can't open PDF files on Safari too and I'm not alone -> [Apple Discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5380531)

So, Wait & See !